# Create a column based on another dataframe values

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = """
    date          id
    2015-10-31    50230
    2015-10-31    48646
    2015-10-31    48748
    2015-10-31    46992
    2015-11-01    46491
    2015-11-01    45347
    2015-11-01    45681
    2015-11-01    46430
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+', index_col=False, parse_dates = ['date'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

df2['Check'] = np.where(datetime.datetime.strftime(df['date'],'%B')=='October',0,1)
```

I have this example I'm working with. What `df2['Check']` is doing is if `df['date'] == 'October'`  then I assign 0, otherwise 1.

`np.where` works fine with other condition, but `strftime` isn't liking the series causing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    df2['Check'] = np.where(datetime.datetime.strftime(df['date'],'%B')=='October',0,1)
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Series'
```

If I loop it takes a long time with my actual data which is about 1M. How can I do this efficiently?

`df2['Check']` should look like this:

```
  Check
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
```

Comment: Use the `.dt` accessor. Use Pandas 0.17. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor). You are getting the error because datetime works with single argument, not arrays.

Comment: Very useful, I'll keep that in mind. Part of anaconda I have 0.16 for now.

Comment: Shouldn't `df['date'].dt.month==9` just work even in `0.16.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly simpler version, using the `month` attribute of the `datetime` object. If that is equal to 10, just map true / false values to your desired  0 / 1 pairs:

```
df2['Check']=df.date.apply(lambda x: x.month==10).map({True:0,False:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

@ako's answer is on the money, but based on @Kartik's and @EdChum's comments here's what I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

data = """
    2015-10-31    50230
    2015-10-31    48646
    2015-10-31    48748
    2015-10-31    46992
    2015-11-01    46491
    2015-11-01    45347
    2015-11-01    45681
    2015-11-01    46430
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data*125000), delimiter='\s+', index_col=False, names=['date','id'], parse_dates = ['date'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

df.shape
(1125000, 2)

%timeit df2['Check']=df.date.apply(lambda x: x.month==10).map({True:0,False:1})
1 loops, best of 3: 2.56 s per loop

%timeit df2['date'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month==10,0,1)
10 loops, best of 3: 80.5 ms per loop
```